# crc32 hash integrated with md5 in python

Tags: algorithm, crc32

> I am trying to create a CRC32
>
> But i keep getting this error for `crcvalue = zlib.crc32(crcvalue)`

**builtins.TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'int'**

Comment: you're trying to perform a CRC on an integer? which is 0? you were taking about computing a CRC for a filename...

Comment: when i attempted it the first time an errors said i was not assigning  a value, but yes i am trying to compute the CRC32 to each file within the for loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `0` to `crc32` instead of the file name. This just makes no sense.

just encode the filename as bytes using ascii encoding and pass those bytes to the crc method:

```
>>> import zlib
>>> x = "filename"
>>> zlib.crc32(x.encode('ascii'))
1007413605
```

Comment: an example of the output i am hoping to achieve is 'Filename: 2215.jpg  SHA1: a26ea006064799dd2a640b5d7edf613a  CRC: '

Comment: could you possibly explain what i was doing wrong VS your method and why x is = to filename